# How do you programmatically turn off the Windows XP Print Spooler service in C#

Tags: c#, windows, windows-xp, console-application

I need to write a small console app (patch) that turns off the print spooler service, does a few things, then starts the print spooler service.  I'd like to write this in C#.  Can someone point me in the right direction?  Thanks in advance!

Comment: It would be easier to just write a script for it. Why C#?

Comment: @Jeff Yates, maybe the "few things" need to be programmmatic.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can probably do that using the ServiceController class :

```
ServiceController controller = new ServiceController("Spooler");
controller.Stop();
...
controller.Start();
```

Comment: Thanks.  This was exactly what I needed to complete the task.

Comment: Adding a call to controller.WaitForStatus may be useful too.

Answer (score 1):

```
net start spooler
net stop spooler
```

http://www.tech-recipes.com/rx/864/windows-service-managing-through-command-line/

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you use the `ServiceController` class to control (i.e. to stop and start) the service whose name is `spooler`.

Comment: Patch complete.  Thanks.  Your input sent me to the right place!